# SmartyException on 1979 Date Modified

Tags: php, ubuntu-16.04, smarty3

I have an issue that has been throwing me to the deep end back and forth. I am using Komodo to edit files over the network. My work sits on a development box that is mounted to a preferred drive on my windows machine.

I figured out the issue I am getting with the Smarty Cache engine is that it throws an exception when a view file has a 1970 timestamp in it.

Meanwhile my infrastructure team is looking at the issue I am wondering if there is no way I can bypass this as I am unable to do any work let alone being productive.

Comment: Maybe Smarty is configured to have a cache with lifetime check. See http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/caching.tpl Try to disable Smarty caching and test again...

Comment: Okay I will do that because I am still experiencing the issue haven't had anyone suggesting any solution with this. Thanks